# Entity Framework get decimal out of range

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

Update：My question is "Why auto add zero", zero don't add by me.

**My Entity**

```
[Precision(11, 6)]
public decimal? EXCHANGE_RATE { get; set; }
```

**My DTO**

```
[Precision(11, 6)]
public virtual decimal? ExchangeRate { get; set; }
```

**My Insert Data**

```
6716844.89
```

Before AddAsync,
the value is ok,
but run AddAsync,
throw exception,

> InnerException    {System.ArgumentException: Parameter value '6716844.890000' is out of range.

```
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__188_0(Task`1 result)    
at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()    
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)    
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) 
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---    
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread) 
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---    
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Relatio…
```

Why the value become 6716844.890000, not 6716844.89 or 6716844.89000

Thanks

Comment: `(11,6)` means you can have 5 integral at most, and 6 fractional digits. Your number has 7 integral digits so it's out of range. The value didn't change, it's displayed in the way you specified - 6 fractional digits

Comment: My question is "Why auto add zero", zero don't add by me.

Comment: The question is wrong. The error complains that the number is greater than the maximum you specified, 99999. `6716844` is greater than `99999`, so you get an  out-of-range exception. Fractional trailing zeroes are insignificant, both in math and computers. You specified that the maximum number of integer digits is `11-6=5`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's not entirely true, at least for T-SQL with implicit conversion e.g. to datetime - too many trailing zeros to fit in datetime will cause conversion to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Your decimal value is out of range, because you have specified wrong precision:

`[Precision(11, 6)]` - Means Precision 11 and Scale 6

`11` is max number of digits allowed in number (all including after point)

`6` is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point in a number. It is guaranteed number of digits after decimal point and it is always reserved.

So, in your case before decimal point allowed only 5 digits.

In value `6716844.890000` you have 13 digits (7 integral digits + 6 after decimal point) and for handling this value your attribute should be:

```
[Precision(13, 6)]
public decimal? EXCHANGE_RATE { get; set; }
```

For further reading: [Precision, scale, and length (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: The problem isn't the 13 digits (trailing 0s don't count) but the 7 integral digits. `(11,6)` means there can only be 5 integral digits

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, actually this is what i explained. Will add more comments.

Comment: The number has 9 digits, not 13. It has only 2 fractional digits, not 6. If the limit was the total number of digits, there would be no problem. Trailing fractional 0s don't matter. SQL Server wouldn't complain about them. It's the integral digits that are above the specified maximum of `99999`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, 6 is aways reserved, you cannot omit zeroes after decimal point.

Comment: My question is "Why auto add zero", zero don't add by me.